# How do divs and spans in PHP include statements work?

Tags: php, include

I'm having trouble understand how exactly INCLUDE statements work.

For example, let's say i have a file, index.htm and a file data.php

Index.htm

```
<div id="1">
contentcontentcontentcontent
</div>

<div id="2">
<?php include 'data.php' ?>
</div>
```

So my question is, does div 2 contain the entirety of data.php? Like, what if data.php has divs and spans of its own? Does div 2 act as a mini page (kind of like a frame) where its contents are displayed only within the parameters of its div?

Also if i apply css style to div 2 to make it 200x200 pixels in the centre of the screen, does that mean that data.php will be displayed exactly there, and only within that 200x200 space?

Comment: did you try your theory out to see what happens?

Comment: Just look at the source code of the generated web page, and you will see what the output exactly is. And read [the PHP manual](http://php.net/include).

Comment: I dont know css yet, i just know a bit about it. I was trying to teach myself php first and plan out the logic of a site im trying to build. I thought i would be able to just get a quick answer so i could continue the logic part without having to start fiddling with css. But apparently i can't do so without getting downrated.

Comment: FWIW, you have a typo in your code. You spelled `include` wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the php include is to allow you to separate your project into smaller sections and reuse code where applicable.

> So my question is, does div 2 contain the entirety of data.php?

Yes, whatever is in the file `data.php` will be placed inside of `div#2`.

> Also if i apply css style to div 2 to make it 200x200 pixels in the
>   centre of the screen, does that mean that data.php will be displayed
>   exactly there, and only within that 200x200 space?

Yes so long as the data does not overflow your container.

A practical example of using an include would be to separate the html that is used to create your menu.  Then in each of your pages you can include the menu file.  Now if you need to make changes to your menu you only have to update one file.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. That gives me a better sense of how i should be segmenting my code.

Comment: Other common uses would be to have a file for all your configuration settings and then include that into your pages, or a file that stores your functions can be included into a page so you may have access to those functions.

Answer (score 2):

If your data.php file outputs only html code, then all of the code from that file will be dumped right into div 2. 
You could say it's "like a frame" but it's really nothing like a frame since a frame is a separate request all together. 
Without knowing what's in your data.php file it's hard to say with 100% certainty what will happen, but with 99% certainty I can say that if data.php spits out html content only, you're going to see it in div 2 - depending on div 2's styling, eh? don't forget that part ;)

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I appreciate the answer!